# How to open an Image without saving another Location?

Tags: android

now file:// uri are not supported. people say to use FileProvider  but i think i have to save image in app data location to use this. is there a way to get  content:// URI Without Saving image in data directory.i want to open image in sd card from gallery. this below code works on old phones, after android 7 it is not working. FileUriExposedException example image file is in dcim folder my old code is this

```
    File pic2toview  = new File(imagepath);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pic2toview), "image/*");
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What do you want to do ? Download a image from server or want to get URI of image saved in device ?

Comment: i want to open /storage/emulated/0/dcim/imagefile.jpg from gallery with my app button click. android 7up its not working every one says to use FileProvider but i dont need to save this image again. i just want to open

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to select an image from gallery by intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

Then it handled in `onActivityResult`,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        imageUrl = data.getData();
  }
}
```

Here `imageUrl` is `Uri` of image selected from gallery.

Comment: no sir i want to open not get image from gallery. i just want to open.  i want to use Intent.ACTION_VIEW  this works but on android 7 it is not working  this link says to use FileProvider   https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-files-though-intents-are-you-ready-for-nougat-70f7e9294a0b

Comment: Ok then, as your requirement you can use `Uri` obtained in `onActivityResult` and show that image in any `imageview`.

Comment: i know the path so i dont need onActivityResult  to get the path and show on my app. i want to open the image from gallery but thank you for help.  i vote you.

Comment: If my answer helps you in any way. Then thanks for it.